# Django - Model Unicode Error

Tags: django, django-models

here is my Model :

```
class Profile(models.Model):
 28     owner = models.OneToOneField(User)
 29     title = models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True)
 30     slogan = models.TextField(null=True)
 31     twitter = models.CharField(max_length = 100,null=True)
 32     web_site = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
 33     email = models.EmailField(max_length = 100,null=True)
 34 
 35     def create_user(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
 36         if created:
 37             Profile.objects.create(owner=instance)
 38 
 39     post_save.connect(create_user, sender=User)
 40 
 41     def __unicode__(self):
 42         return self.title
```

and it throws :

```
TypeError at /superadmin/auth/user/

coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found
```

i tried to return each field. but still same..

what i am missin?

thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation [specifically cautions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/fields/#null) against using `null=True` on CharFields. Don't do it.

Comment: thank you it worked! one more question ; how can i set username as unicode in this model?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand that question.

Comment: now it returns email field as unicode object ( p.e in django default admin or shell) i want to make it username. i mean ; User.username

Comment: So do `return self.owner.username`.